# ForeignKey to manyToManyField django evolve error when changing model

Tags: django, django-models, pyevolve

I can't change my model from ForeignKey to ManyToManyField with evolve

**my model:**

```
 class Orden(models.Model):
 perfil = models.ForeignKey(Perfil, blank=True, null=True)
```

**I try to change to**

```
perfil = models.ManyToManyField(Perfil, blank=True, null=True)
```

If I create a new database all works fine.

**this is the output:**

```
python manage.py evolve --hint  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>  
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)  
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399,   in execute_from_command_line  
utility.execute()  
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute  
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)  
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv  
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)  
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute  
output = self.handle(*args, **options)  
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_evolution/management/commands/evolve.py", line 60, in handle  
self.evolve(*app_labels, **options)  
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_evolution/management/commands/evolve.py", line 119, in evolve  
hinted_evolution = diff.evolution()  
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_evolution/diff.py", line 246, in evolution
ATTRIBUTE_DEFAULTS[prop])  
KeyError: 'field_type'
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/

Comment: You'll need to perform a migration. Did you solve this?